# How to preserve exact colors in Imagemagick svg to png conversion?

Tags: colors, imagemagick, inkscape

Let's take a simple example SVG:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadow" x="-200%" y="-200%" width="500%" height="500%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#000000" flood-opacity="0.5" result="floodColor"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3.0" result="blur"/>
      <feOffset in="blur" dx="0.0" dy="0.0" result="offsetBlur"/>
      <feComposite in="floodColor" in2="offsetBlur" operator="in" result="shadow"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="shadow" mode="normal"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect
    x="10"
    y="10"
    width="80"
    height="80"
    rx="10"
    stroke-width="5"
    stroke="#131414"
    fill="#212124"
    filter="url(#shadow)"
  />
</svg>
```

Note that the fill color of the rectangle is `#212124`, as defined in the source:

[image]

If I convert this SVG to PNG via Imagemagick's `convert test.svg test.png` I'm getting:

[image]

Note that the fill color has changed to `#1C1C21`. I have checked the colors with multiple image viewers/editors to rule out the possibility that the difference comes from displaying.

Why is Imagemagick changing the color, and what can I do to keep the same color values exactly?

---

I came across the [color management](https://imagemagick.org/script/color-management.php) of Imagemagick (I'm confused by the RGB vs sRGB topic in general), and tried to add a `-set colorspace RGB`. This results in:

[image]

So `#222126` is now closer to `#212124`, but still no exact color matching.

In case it matters, relevant software versions are:

- ImageMagick 6.9.7-4
- Inkscape 0.92.3

Comment: Side note: I also don't understand why the size changes from 100x100 to 95x95, but that is maybe a different question. In practice this can be "solved" by re-specifying the size via `-resize 100x100` in the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following SVG file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="shadow" x="-200%" y="-200%" width="500%" height="500%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#000000" flood-opacity="0.5" result="floodColor"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3.0" result="blur"/>
      <feOffset in="blur" dx="0.0" dy="0.0" result="offsetBlur"/>
      <feComposite in="floodColor" in2="offsetBlur" operator="in" result="shadow"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="shadow" mode="normal"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect
    x="10"
    y="10"
    width="80"
    height="80"
    rx="10"
    stroke-width="5"
    stroke="#131414"
    fill="#212124"
    filter="url(#shadow)"
  />
</svg>
```

And the following command:

```
convert test.svg test.png
```

I got this image as the result:

[image: GIMP screenshot]

As you can see, the measured color is exactly `#212124`. Also, the image is exactly 100x100 pixels:

```
$ file test.png 
test.png: PNG image data, 100 x 100, 16-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

I am using ImageMagick version 6.9.11.

Comment: Interesting. Do you have Inkscape installed? I do, which (to my knowledge) means that Imagemagick is using it internally for the conversion. So it is either that, or the Imagemagick version that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, I have Inkscape 1.0.1 installed